# knockout.js - prepend <td> to those generated by <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

while my viewmodel looks something like this:

```
    "rows" : [
        {   "name": "row_1",
            "columns": [
                { "name" : "column_1", "value" : "value_1_1"},
                { "name" : "column_2", "value" : "value_1_2"},
                { "name" : "column_3", "value" : "value_1_3"},
                { "name" : "column_4", "value" : "value_1_4"},
                { "name" : "column_5", "value" : "value_1_5"}
            ]
        },
        {   "name": "row_2",
            "columns": [
                { "name" : "column_1", "value" : "value_2_1"},
                { "name" : "column_2", "value" : "value_2_2"},
                { "name" : "column_3", "value" : "value_2_3"},
                { "name" : "column_4", "value" : "value_2_4"},
                { "name" : "column_5", "value" : "value_2_5"}
            ]
        },
        ...
     ]
```

And I built a table using something like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
     <td><span data-bind="text: value"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This all populates fine, but I want each row to have a `<td>(row_name)</td>` prepended to it.

Is there a straight forward way to prepend that 'labeling' `<td>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
            <td><span data-bind="text: value"></span></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This approach is known as 'containerless control flow syntax' and is ideal for this scenario; the KO docs give this example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Header item</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
        <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

ref: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: That is right on the money. I didn't know about 'containerless control flow syntax' and it seems super handy. I knew ko had to have  thought of this sceneario. Cheers!

Comment: thanks! yep, it certainly is super handy - I use it a lot and once you've got the hang of it you'll find it useful in all sorts of places. You can use it with if and with, too.